# Error Desc: Exception from HRESULT: 0x800A0046 (CTL_E_PERMISSIONDENIED)

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

Hi can any one advice how I can sort out this error

```
 **Exception from HRESULT: 0x800A0046 (CTL_E_PERMISSIONDENIED)**
```

Note that this error is not comming for all of the file rarely it is throwing, while writing string data in the file.

please find the below code which i am using in VB.net

```
Dim fso, file

strResult = "this is the sample string data"

strPath = it is local path only.

fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
file = fso.opentextfile(strPath, ForWriting, True)
file.write(strResult)
file.Close()
```

Comment: can any one advice for this please, i am searching so many partals,i dint find out am not satisfied with that answers however i am creating the file in the local system and writing in it, hope it will not permission issue, error also it was throwing rare case not for all the files, or is there any alternate approach in vb.net?

Comment: dear guys kindly advice is there any way for this issue to simulate?

Comment: Did you even try the answer or just down vote it? The answer provided will do what u need it do, otherwise why don't you post your error. Also it best to wrap code in try catch so you know where your issue is.

Answer (score 0):

The error is being thrown because either, you don't have permission to edit the file or because the file is in use by another process or another user. Also using the legacy FileSystemObject isn't a good idea.  Use the managed libraries from the .NET framework because it will provide you with better error support. See example below as how you can accomplish the same thing below...

```
 Try
   File.WriteAllText("Your data", "FILE")
 Catch ex As Exception
   MsgBox (ex.Message) 'Or however you want to handle this...
 End Try
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Without more information about what your file system is like, what permissions you have, and what exactly are you trying to do and use in your program, there is little to no way of knowing how to help you.

However, I've encountered this problem in the past due to legacy DLLs mixed in with more recent technologies - such as .Net 1 vs .Net 4.5.

Old DLLs under .Net 4.5 and above are a pain in the backside to manage and make sure they run properly. They cause memory leaks, they don't respect memory properly and they are hardcoded in many ways to do things that .Net 4.5 and above would do better these days.

I suggest you provide us with your project settings, and your COM references, because one of them is most likely the reason you're getting this error.

It's a process of elimination. Eliminate one Reference at a time, comment out code, debug, etc until you find the culprit DLL that gives you the problem. AND THEN you need to decide whether to use another DLL, another Reference or better yet, do without that offending DLL in the first place.

Good luck,